# Kmean clustering on image segmentation

Tags: image, k-means

Is there any difference between following kmeans clustering?

a) Convert image to grayscale and perform kmeans on 1D feature vectors

b) Keep 3 channels RGB, and perform kmeans on 3D feature vectors

c) Get image histogram and perform kmeans on the distribution

The first solution is definitely faster, but is there will be a difference? Maybe some pixels has different RGB, but has the same intensity?

Answer (score 0):

1) Conversion to Gray from RGB is not usually done by simply averaging the values (See [Grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)). If it is done using that unusual way, even then the euclidean distance used in K-means will give different distances for your cases (a) and (b) - resulting in different clustering- as you mentioned [edit]. However, since the gray value is a weighted sum (with weights different from 1/3), taking euclidean distance between RGBs is different from taking the difference on the gray values - so they are different.

2) I am not entirely clear on your (c) but perform k-means on the distribution is weird. May be you meant using K-means as a model to fit the distribution, in order to identify the peaks and valleys in the histogram? If that is the case, it is a slight variation of case (a) itself. They could be very similar (not sure if they are identical, may be!) if you think of case (c) as a rewrite of case (a) by grouping all the identical terms in the sum-of-squared error and rewriting it as a multiplier times the difference. [as in: x1 + x2 + x1 + x3 being written as 2x1 + x2 + x3]